# cant convert .py to .exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, eel

Actually im working on a face recognition system which contains few sound files few folders and a hand full of python files. Im using EEL to include html and CSS to the front end. Now i want to know how to include the folders into the exe .Then whenever i click the exe file in Dist folder I get a error message in cmd but it just closes in a second, I need to see that message properly in order to debug

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from datetime import datetime
import eel
import dataset_capture2
import train_dataset_new
import offline_records

eel.init('assets')


@eel.expose
def dummy(dummy_param):
    print('i got a parameter'+dummy_param)
    return "String_value", 1, 1.2, True, [1, 2, 3, 4], {"name": "eel"}

# root=Tk()

# root.configure(background="white")


@eel.expose
def capture_dataset(uid, name):
    dataset_capture2.clickfun(uid, name)


@eel.expose
def train_dataset():
    if train_dataset_new.train_model() == 2:
        return 3


@eel.expose
def take_attendance():
    offline_records.qr()


@eel.expose
def open_workbook2():
    os.startfile('Attendance Report.xlsx')


@eel.expose
def Manual_Entry(uin):
    print("uin"+uin)
    offline_records.facee(uin)

@eel.expose
def Save_Attendance():
    if offline_records.readFromdb()==2:
        return 3

os.system("pause")
eel.start('/index.html')
os.system("pause")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a folder structure like that:

[image]

...including your image in subfolder "eye", and where your code in the "face" folder is like that:

```
from PIL import Image
import time

image_from_subfolder=Image.open("eye\Experience_in_AI.png")
print("Image from subfolder opened...")
image_from_subfolder.show()
print("Image was shown...")
```

...which very well works in your python-development environment.

But, after making the .exe by pyinstaller to be able to debug, in windows open your cmd:

[image]

...and run it like shown in the screenshot above. You can see the errors in the screen. I think that by slightly modifying your image path description you will solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever i click the exe file in Dist folder I get a error message in
> cmd but it just closes in a second, I need to see that message
> properly in order to debug

To see the error message, open the EXE from the command line, something like:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\demo>cd C:\Projects\demos\dist\app

C:\Projects\demos\dist\app>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
    <message here>
```

Then your error message will remain visible. You don't need the `os.system("pause")`, so remove that because it could cause other issues.

> face recognition system which contains few sound files few folders and
> a hand full of python files. Im using EEL to include html and CSS to
> the front end. Now i want to know how to include the folders into the
> exe .

PyInstaller requires you to specify the non-Python source files that should be included in the EXE when building the EXE. See [PyInstaller Usage](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), specifically the `--add-data` flag. I mention this because you commented that there are some sound files (and I see an XLSX too).

Also, note that behind-the-scenes, Eel will add your "web" folder (or whatever you named it) to PyInstaller with the same `--add-data` flag, so you can skip that one.